# Запись массива файлов в SQL таблицу

Tags: массивы, java, sql

Добрый вечер всем.
Задача заключается в следующем:

1. Нужно загрузить массив файлов в sql таблицу
2. при ошибке откатить изменения

Вот попытался сделать для загрузки одного файла, работает:

```
private String nameDivision;
private int id_doc;
private int id_attach;
private String name;
private String size;

private List<File> fileList;

private Connection con;
private ResultSet rs;
private PreparedStatement pstm;

public FileLoader() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ConnectDB connect = new ConnectDB();
    connect.setConnect();
    con = connect.getConnect();
}

public void LoadFileInDB() throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException {
    String INSERT_PICTURE = "insert into archive_upload_files(id_document, name, attachement) values (?, ?, ?)";
    FileInputStream fis = null;

    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    File file = new File("C:\\Java план.txt");
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    pstm = con.prepareStatement(INSERT_PICTURE);
    pstm.setString(1, "11" );
    pstm.setString(2, file.getName());
    pstm.setBinaryStream(3, fis, (int) file.length());
    System.out.println(file.getName()+" "+file.length());
    pstm.executeUpdate();
    con.commit();
}
```

Как переделать под условия задачи, чтобы произвести быструю и надежную загрузку? Точнее я представляю, что это можно сделать циклом и добавить 100 файлов, 100 раз обратившись к базе. Как это сделать быстро и элегантно, с возможностью отката при ошибке.
Метод `public boolean LoadFileInDB()` будет иметь на входе

```
public boolean LoadFileInDB(List<File> fileList) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот Вам разжованный пример как это сделать: [Java: How to Load CSV file into Database](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-load-csv-file-to-database/)

Comment: @Iranda спасибо! так насного лучше -)